# What is < and [ in Regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, match, string-matching

I've got

```
var $pBracketVisualOpenRegExp = /[/ ;
```

and

```
var $pBracketFunctionOpenRegExp = /</ ;
```

in my Javascript.
but it doesent works with .match()

```
$MatchArray = $String.match(/</);
```

the other Brackets and Signs { ( " works fine.

Comment: Try escaping `[`, like this `\[`

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=regex+cheat+sheet and http://www.google.com/search?q=regex+quick+reference . or any official documentation.

Comment: The character < may be special. It mark beginning of word.

Answer (score 0):

`/[/` is not a valid RegEx. See http://regex101.com/r/qO5hR4.
`/</` should match `<` literally though. Try some regex playground when developing the expressions. Im much faster this way. Good places are http://regex101.com and http://lea.verou.me/regexplained/.

Answer (score 0):

`/[/` is not a valid RegEx. I tried your code for `/</` and it works.

```
var $pBracketFunctionOpenRegExp = /</ ;

$String = 'aaa<lklkd';
$MatchArray = $String.match($pBracketFunctionOpenRegExp); //result ['<']
```

Answer (score 0):

"\<" will match the empty string at the beginning of word.